# How to select multiple columns from a table in an IF ELSE stored procedure

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure which has 3 IF ELSE sections, in one of them I would like to select 2 columns to evaluate but am getting this error :
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

In this case the guid&number are unique, here is the section of the procedure in question:

````
IF ((SELECT [guid],[number] from [tws] where [guid] = @ReferenceNumber and @Number = [number] and ([instruction_submitted] = '' or [instruction_submitted] is null )) is not null)  
SET @ReturnValue = 2
ELSE ```
````

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IF` in "SQL"). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT [guid],[number]
            from [tws]
            where [guid] = @ReferenceNumber and @Number = [number] and
                  ([instruction_submitted] = '' or [instruction_submitted] is null )
           )
  )
BEGIN 
    SET @ReturnValue = 2;
END;
ELSE . . .
```

I also strongly encourage you to use `BEGIN`/`END` around in `IF` statements -- that makes it less error-prone to add additional statements in the future.

Comment: Thanks I had tried using the exists in this manner but as you have pointed out the BEGIN/END is what was not letting this work.